# How to remove antialias edge in ImageMagick when converting to a binary bitmap?

Tags: imagemagick, alpha, antialiasing, bitmapimage

We're doing a cognitive experiment that requires flashing 480 black-and-white images at high speed against a neutral-gray background. The image shown is detail at about 300% zoom; the full display is 932 x 612; there are actually other clusters similar to this one elsewhere on the screen.
[image: Closeup of bitmap file over RGB 192,192,192 background]
We have to generate these images in a source app and later display them in the experimental app. At first, we were using 24-bit PNG's with the background color built in, but despite the size of each file hovering around 10KB, the total file payload of 480 is too large and takes way too long to preload. We can, however, set a default background color in the app and put up 1-bit images. Although we can change the background color in the source application, we don't have control over bit depth there, so we are stuck generating screen captures and then downsampling to binary. We have tried this with original images that sit on both a white background and the gray background. Using ImageMagick, both of these commands yield similar results:

`magick gray.png -transparent "rgb(192,192,192)" -alpha set -depth 1 out\gray-out.bmp` (or `.png`)

`magick white.png -transparent white -alpha set -depth 1 out\white-out.bmp` (or `.png`)

The PNGs are coming out to 1.5K to 5K, so this is where we want to be. However, we're stuck with that problem aliased edge whether we start with gray- or white-background images. We've also tried the `-fuzz` argument (1-99%) to no effect. The resulting pseudoalias artifact that we see in these 1-bit files is the same in multiple apps, so apparently it must be built into the output file generated by ImageMagick's attempt to filter the edge, and not an artifact of any single app or the OS.

We don't quite get how an alpha channel can even be attached to a 1-bit image if it is not strictly RGBA: an alpha channel with a 1-bit image doesn't even make sense. But if an alpha channel isn't being included, then where is the map coming from in a nonbinary image to distinguish that "white" edge from a nonwhite surface? It's not the destination apps. The output files must either not be strictly binary, or else ImageMagick is not computing the channel exactly to the contour edges. (When we remove the `-alpha` argument, ImageMagick generates a larger file; the aliasing (e.g., when we place into PowerPoint and select Transparent Color to white) may appear in slightly different places, but the effect is essentially the same.

The question is, how is it possible to remove this artifact in a 1-bit image using ImageMagick? We'd like to get the file sizes down to the minimum.

Comment: I tried `-depth 8` and later `-depth 2` and `-depth 24`, all without `-alpha set`. These all yielded PNG files of around 5 KB, and they display properly, without the artifact.

Comment: An alpha channel appears unnecessary to various apps as long as the transparent color is specified in the PNG. Yet I'd appreciate a qualification about when alpha channels are necessary and when transparency. Our experience with alpha channels is for color images of 24 RGB for video and 32 bit for CMYK process printing; we are less clear how they relate to transparent color setting -- it would appear the two should be mutually exclusive.

Comment: I can't tell from your question and comments what the problem is, how the images are generated or whether you have solved it... please clarify those aspects if you don't have a solution. Thank you.